# An idea to model a one-dimensional strongly coupled(/mercury?) thermometer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature

We introduce the partition function with $\beta = \frac{1}{k_b T}$ and $T$ as temperature and $H$ the Hamiltonian as

$$ Z = \text{Tr} e^{- \beta H }$$

We also introduce the time average of say $\lambda(t)$ as notation: $\langle \lambda(t) \rangle_t$

Let's say I have a $1$-dimensional material with thermal expansion $\alpha$:

$$ \alpha l_0 = \frac{\Delta l}{\Delta T}$$

where $l$ is the length of the system.

This is the same as saying:

$$ \frac{l}{l_0} - 1 = \alpha T$$

One can assume this to mean if there are $N$ particles (particle number `operator) and one divides it then the average spacing in a uniform material's particles is given by:

$$  \frac{\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t}{l_0}  - \frac{1}{\langle \langle N \rangle \rangle_t} = \frac{\alpha T}{\langle \langle N \rangle \rangle_t}$$

where $x_i$ is the $i$'th particle's position adjacent to the $i+1$ particle's position and the length of the system is given by $l \sim  \langle_t \langle x_1 - x_{\langle \langle N \rangle \rangle_t} \rangle \rangle_t $

where $\langle x_1 \rangle \geq \langle x_2 \rangle \geq \langle x_3 \rangle \geq \langle x_4 \rangle \geq \dots $

The average spacing is given by:
$$\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t =\langle \langle x_j - x_{j+1} \rangle \rangle_t$$

Thus, we have a integral equation must satisfy:

$$  {\langle \langle N \rangle \rangle_t} \frac{\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t}{l_0}  - 1 = 
{\alpha T}$$

Writing in bra-ket notation:

$$  {\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t} \frac{\langle  \langle \psi | x_i - x_{i+1} |  \psi \rangle \rangle_t}{l_0}  - 1 = 
{\alpha T}$$

Let the time evolution at a later time $t+ dt$ be $|\psi + \delta  \psi \rangle = |\psi \rangle + | \delta \psi \rangle $. Hence,

$$  {\langle \langle \psi + \delta  \psi  |N|\psi + \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t} \frac{\langle  \langle \psi + \delta  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |  \psi + \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}{l_0}  - 1 = 
{\alpha T}$$

Subtracting the above and keeping first order $| \delta \psi \rangle$:

$$ \frac{\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t}{l_0} ( {\langle \langle  \delta  \psi  |N|\psi  \rangle \rangle_t} +
{\langle \langle \psi  |N| \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}
) + \frac{{\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t}}{l_o} (
\langle  \langle  \delta  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \psi  \rangle \rangle_t + \langle  \langle  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t
 ) = 0$$

$$ \implies - \frac{\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t}{{\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t}} = \frac{\langle  \langle  \delta  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \psi  \rangle \rangle_t + \langle  \langle  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}{ {\langle \langle  \delta  \psi  |N|\psi  \rangle \rangle_t} +
{\langle \langle \psi  |N| \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}}$$

Multiplying the square of ${\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t}$ both sides:

$$ \implies - l_o(1+ \alpha T ) = ({\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t})^2 \frac{\langle  \langle  \delta  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \psi  \rangle \rangle_t + \langle  \langle  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}{ {\langle \langle  \delta  \psi  |N|\psi  \rangle \rangle_t} +
{\langle \langle \psi  |N| \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}}$$

Note: the above equation uses thermodynamics limit where $\langle \langle \psi  |N|   \psi  \rangle \rangle_t \to \infty $ since we are using infinitesimals $dt$ in the definition of $\langle \psi | \delta \psi \rangle + \langle \delta \psi | \psi \rangle \to 0$. We can view $l_o$ ands $\alpha$ as boundary conditions. Hence,

$$  C = - \lim_{\langle \psi | \delta \psi \rangle + \langle \delta \psi | \psi \rangle \to 0} \lim_{\langle \langle N  \rangle \rangle_t \to \infty; \langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t \to 0 }({\langle \langle \psi |N |\psi \rangle \rangle_t})^2 \times 
 \frac{\langle  \langle  \delta  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \psi  \rangle \rangle_t + \langle  \langle  \psi  | x_i - x_{i+1} |   \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}{ {\langle \langle  \delta  \psi  |N|\psi  \rangle \rangle_t} +
{\langle \langle \psi  |N| \delta  \psi  \rangle \rangle_t}}$$

Where $C$ is given by:

$$C = l_o(1+ \alpha T ) = \lim_{\langle \langle N  \rangle \rangle_t \to \infty; \langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t \to 0 } \langle \langle N \rangle \rangle_t {\langle \langle x_i - x_{i+1} \rangle \rangle_t}$$

### Question

The above was done while thinking about mercury a strongly coupled system. Does such an approach already exist in the literature? Is it possible to verify with an explicit solution (regardless of a strongly coupled system)?

Comment: Just for clarification: $|\psi_i\rangle$ ist the full, $N$-parrticle, state or one-particle state at any of the sites? Are the single particles confined in 0-d (at any of the positions, $n\in\lbrace1,\ldots,N\rbrace$  which are constant, in some state $i$) or in 1-d (free, possibly interacting particles confined onsome interval with given one-particle states)? May the particles jump between sites? If so: bosons or fermions and what are onsite interactions?

Comment: There would also be some boundary conditions (which would be the walls of the thermometer and perhaps some internal pressure constraints). Which might be required to model this?

Comment: @denklo I've massively edited the question. In light of that the particles are indistinguishable the notation only makes sense in way $\langle x_1 \rangle \geq \langle x_2 \rangle \geq \langle x_3 \rangle \geq \langle x_4 \rangle \geq \dots$. As for boson versus fermion - Now I'd say what time of thermometer are you using? Note: I was thinking of mercury personally (I'm uncertain what the spin system of that is)

Comment: * what type of thermometer